# Error to open dbfs in Databricks workspace azure

Tags: azure, databricks

I already active DBFS in Databricks workspace admin and up a cluster. But when I try to open I get the following message:

**DBFS file browser:** The Azure container does not exists

Comment: Have you mounted your ADLS in databricks?
Can you share the image of the DBFS file browser with error details?

Answer (score 1):

If you've mounted the Azure Blob Storage container to a specific mount point in **DBFS**, verify the mount point path in the file browser. It should reflect the configured mount point.

Syntax for mounting:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source: str,
  mount_point: str,
  encryption_type: Optional[str] = "",
  extra_configs: Optional[dict[str:str]] = None
)
```

Learn more about [Mounting cloud object storage on Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/mounts).

Make sure Azure Databricks has read access to the container in Azure Blob Storage. Permissions can be managed through **Azure RBAC (Role-Based Access Control)**.

Access to storage resources is managed by assigning roles to a Microsoft Enterprise ID application registration linked with the storage account. Depending on specific requirements, additional roles may need to be assigned.

To assign roles on a storage account, the user must have the Owner or User Access Administrator Azure RBAC role on the storage account.

Learn more about [Assigning roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/connect/storage/aad-storage-service-principal#assign-roles).